# trying to upload big video to facebook using resumable file method

Tags: api, facebook, facebook-graph-api, resumable

Im trying to upload a video to a group using graph api. I could upload video in my pc without any error but when I try to upload same video from my server (512MB RAM) it give me memory error. I saw a method to upload video using resumable method but I couldn't find any example. Can someone give me an example code for the process.

sorry for the stupid question Im Newbie :)

Comment: What are you doing and what error do you get?

Comment: I get memory quota exceed error when try to upload 1GB File

Comment: So what does your code look like and exactly what error do you get?

Comment: Today I tried to chunk file using split command and it got worked :)

Comment: Thank you for reply me good luck ❤️